# Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу C++

Tags: c++

Выдает:

> Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.
> _Left было 0xCCCCCCCC.

в строке `getline(cin, book.id.strId);`

Код программы:

```
struct product {
    string name;
    short type;
    union idVal{
        idVal() {};
        ~idVal() {};

        string strId;
        int intId;
    } id;
};

void a15() {
    product book;
    book.name = "Имя";
    cout << "Введите тип ID для продукта " << book.name << endl;
    cout << "0 - string; 1 - integer." << endl;
    cin >> book.type;

    cout << "Введите ID продукта: ";
    string input;
    switch (book.type)
    {
    case 0:
        getline(cin, book.id.strId);
        break;
    case 1:
        cin >> book.id.intId;
        break;
    }
                
    switch (book.type) {
    case 0:
        cout << book.id.strId << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << book.id.intId << endl;
    }
}
```

Как я понимаю, проблема именно в использовании объединения, чем можно заменить для корректной работы?

***Upd.:***

заменил код с первым свитчем на такой:

```
string input;
switch (book.type)
{
case 0:
    getline(cin, input);
    new (&book.id.strId) string(input);
    break;
case 1:
    cin >> book.id.intId;
    break;
}
```

Ну и в конце программы удаляю: `book.id.strId.~basic_string();`

Comment: Замените на структуру, или на `::std::variant`.

Comment: `union` с полями-объектами с нетривиальными конструкторами — это, как бы выразиться... Словом, это то, чего стоит избегать.

Comment: Спасибо, нужно было решение именно с `union`, но впредь буду использовать `variant`

Comment: Если с `union`, то надо было бы с С-строкой работать. Для таких полей `variant` слишком тяжеловесен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 варианта:

```
switch (book.type)
{
case 0:
    new (&book.id.strId) std::string();
    std::cin.get();
    std::getline(std::cin, book.id.strId);
    break;
case 1:
    std::cin >> book.id.intId;
    break;
}
```

При использовании getline после cin не забывайте про то, что в буфере cin остается '\n', который и считывает geltine, возвращая пустую строку

```
switch (book.type)
{
case 0:
    std::cin.get();
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    book.id.strId = input;
    break;
case 1:
    std::cin >> book.id.intId;
    break;
}
```

По поводу разрушения union-а, состоящего из неинтегральных типов можно прочитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106941/is-a-union-members-destructor-called) (так же там есть и пример кода)